# Define grammar in Xtext for optional array dimensions

Tags: grammar, xtext

I'm trying to define grammar in xtext for arrays where dimensions can be empty like `int[][]` or `int[5][10]`

My grammar looks like:

```
ArrayType: 
     [BasicType] ('['(dimension+=Expression)?']')+;
```

The problem with that rule when I use `int[][]` is there is no way from the model to know how many `[]` included because `dimension` list would be empty.

So I wonder if there is a way in xtext to default value like `0` in case `Expression` wasn't found? Otherwise what is the best way to handle such situation without changing the metamodel?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

By no means an Xtext expert but can't you add an intermediary term:

```
ArrayType: 
  [BasicType] dimensions=Dimension+;

Dimension:
  ('['(size+=Expression)?']')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought about this but I don't want to change the metamodel.
The correct answer so would be:
 `ArrayType: [BasicType] dimensions+=Dimension+
  Dimension: '[' index=Expression? ']'`